# Difference between URL::to and URL::route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

What is the difference between

```
<a href=" {{ URL::route('/account/register') }}" >Register 1 </a>
```

and

```
<a href=" {{ URL::to('/account/register') }}" >Register 2 </a>
```

I defined the routes.php as

```
Route::get('/account/register','RegisterController@create');
```

When I click on 'Register 1' I got the following error

```
Route [/account/register] not defined.
```

But when I click on 'Register 2' ,it goes to the

```
RegisterController@create
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[URL::route](https://github.com/igorw/laravel-framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L174) gets the URL to a named route. So in your case, if you name your route like this:

```php
Route::get('/account/register', [
    'name' => 'register', 
    'uses' => 'RegisterController@create'
]);
```

then you will be able to use

```blade
<a href="{{ URL::route('register') }}" >Register 1</a>
```

in blade templates.

Answer (score 9):

Url::route is used only if you have named routes. So if I called my route "my route" then I could call it like so:
URL::route('my route');

But if you want to direct to a route that only has a destination and is not named, then you should use URL::to

Answer (score 0):

## First Create Named Routes

```
Route::get('register',function(){
  return "register page";
})->name('register');
```

## then you will be able to use

```
 $url = route('register');

<a href="{{url($url)}}">Register</a>
```